# Technical difference between varbinary(8000) and varbinary(max) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, varbinary, varbinarymax

Except for the different amount of data it can store, what is the implementation / storage difference between `varbinary(8000)` and `varbinary(max)` in SQL Server 2019?

The [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) just say to use `varbinary(max)` for column data with more than 8000 bytes, without going in any details, how e.g. a **theoretical** (if one could create it) `varbinary(9999)` would be different from `varbinary(max)`.

Comment: In this duplicate, it's the same reason even though it's `varchar` instead of `varbinary. It would also be the same for `nvarchar(4000)` as that uses UTF-16 which requires 2 bytes per character.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, this answers my question. Thanks :-)

Comment: The reason for the max of (8000) is an underneath the hood thing. Each page of storage is 8k. If you go above that, you need (max). It should be obvious, but if you have anything other columns in the table varbinary(8000) would be unwise.